# Jquery fade in and out a div in parallax animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax

I have a home page which just shows some logo and etxt and a div on click it scroll to another page.

Now I have done the animation part of scrolling.
What I need is when someone click on FIND YOUR HEART the nav div must come as a fade in effect.
I tried window method and take the scroll position, but nothing works.

Comment: Post your code, preferably as a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to scroll to the navigation-div use this code:

```
$("#findYourHeartDiv").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($("#navDiv").offset().top)
  }, 800);
});
```

If you want to fade it in, hide it first (e.g. with css `display:none;`), then use this code:

```
$("#findYourHeartDiv").click(function() {
  $("#navDiv").fadeIn(); 
});
```

You can combine both to scroll to it and fade it in:

```
$("#findYourHeartDiv").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($("#navDiv").offset().top)
    }, 
    500,
    function() {
      //animation complete function
      $("#navDiv").slideDown();
    });
});
```

To fade in if the user scrolls to a position:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function () {
  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(); // the scroll position
  if(wintop>$("#navDiv").offset().top) {
    $("#navDiv").fadeIn();
  }
  else {
    $("#navDiv").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: HI, 
The fade in works perfectly when i click on the link,
but i need that when user scroll the mouse then it also gets fade in. How can i do that.

I am not getting what is the first code is for, and neither it do anything to my design.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/
It can help you.. :)